# URL Mapping issue - Spring web MVC

Tags: spring

I'm a newbie with Spring and web MVC module. Basically, i have the following :

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

abc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="myPkg" />


<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
</bean>
```

And i have a controller, related parts are :

```
@Controller
public class ABCController {

@RequestMapping("/user/welcome")
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

    //code

}
```

Now whenever i try to access `http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/welcome`

it gives me 404.

Logs say that "mapped url '/user/welcome' onto handler 'ABCController' but it failed to map URI [/**MYAPP**/user/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'abc-dispatcher' .

Totally confused. I have checked all the threads where we specify a mapping twice, but that's not the case here. I must be missing something!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The URL should be `http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/user/welcome`. Indeed, unless the alwaysUseFullPath property of the handler is set to true, the servlet-mapping is prepended to the request mapping URL to form the full path.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-handlermapping for details:

> alwaysUseFullPath
>
> If true , Spring uses the full path within the current Servlet context to find an appropriate handler. If false (the default), the
>   path within the current Servlet mapping is used. For example, if a
>   Servlet is mapped using /testing/* and the alwaysUseFullPath property
>   is set to true, /testing/viewPage.html is used, whereas if the
>   property is set to false, /viewPage.html is used.

Comment: Thanks.. that worked :) One follow-up question if that's ok.. I am including static resources like css and js in jsp's but the url gives 404. Link results in /user/welcome/resources/css/abc.css when i want the url to look like /resources/css/abc.css .. Any pointers on that?

Comment: Ask another question, and tell what the context path is, where the resources are stored, and the code used to generate the URLs.

Answer (score 5):

It's' been added `context:component-scan` element into the sample context file snippet but there is no `<annotation-driven/>` element that says spring framework to look for controllers annotated with `@Controller`

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was that I was using the deprecated **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping**, and even if setting the *alwaysUseFullPath* to true, it didn't take effect, however replacing DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping in benefit of **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** with the *alwaysUseFullPath* set to true solved the problem.

```
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```