# Spring DispatcherServlet: No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an issue implementing a very simple page using spring mvc 3.2.4.RELEASE.

My controller looks like this:

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class MembersDetailsController {
    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/member/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayMember(@PathVariable String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
        return "member";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/member", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayMember() {
        System.out.println("Empty");
        return "member";
    }
}
```

When I call

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/member
```

the respective method is being executed as desired. However, wenn I call

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/member/test
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/member/test/
```

I get a 404 with the log-output:

```
WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/member/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Whats really weired is the a previous log says:

```
INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/member/{name}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String 
INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/member],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String
```

Which means that the mapping should be correct as far as I understand this.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <display-name>Mitgliederdatenbank</display-name>

    <!--Configuration-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>hibernateSessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!--Spring Security Filter-->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--Context Loader-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <!-- Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ui/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginfailed</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/member/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Could anybody please give me a hint what went wrong here?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `@Transactional` annotation?

Comment: Do other controllers work normally or is this only controller in your app? The mapping log that you have included, is it trimmed down? It usually displays (at least in Spring 3.1) Controller class it was mapped to as well.

Comment: Please show your web.xml and your context path.

Comment: Removing the @Transactional annotation doesn't change anything. I added the web.xml to the description.

Comment: The other controllers work fine.

Comment: @KresimirNesek Yes, it is cropped a bit. But it is pointing to the right controller and method.

Comment: seems unlikely but try `http://127.0.0.1:8080/member/test` (no ending slash)

Comment: @DwB I already tried this. Please see my question. I have shown both cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the problem is the same one as described here [URL Mapping issue - Spring web MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692837/url-mapping-issue-spring-web-mvc) .

Unless you use alwaysUseFullPath spring mvc will match * part to the mapping you specified (e.g. /member/member/test ). See docs for alwaysUseFullPath here (section 17.4) http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html .

However, unfortunately, this property is not exposed through  xml configuration element (if you're using xml configuration) so if you'd like your mappings to work the way you discribed in your question you'll need to configure it as described here: http://blog.sarathonline.com/2013/07/enable-alwaysusefullpath-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem and solved problem by using

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

This tag will configure two beans DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.

Also I added tag to my dispatcher servlet config file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="PATH WHERE FIND CONTROLLERS" />
```