# Spring Rest API- No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

Tags: java, json, eclipse, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying execute my rest api that returns data in json, but is not mapping url.

I am getting the message:

PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

ADVERTÊNCIA: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ZombieNetwork/survivors] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>ZombieNetwork</display-name>

</web-app>
```

ApplicationContextConfig.java

```
package Config;


    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration

    @ComponentScan("zombienetwork.*")

    public class ApplicationContextConfig {


       // No need ViewSolver



       // Other declarations if needed ...

    }
```

SpringWebAppInitializer.java

```
package Config;

import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        // UTF8 Charactor Filter.
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");       
    }

}
```

WebMvcConfig.java

```
package Config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

SurvivorController.java

```
package controller;

import java.util.List;

import dao.SurvivorDAO;
import model.Survivor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SurvivorController {

    @Autowired
    private SurvivorDAO survivorDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/survivors", //
            method = RequestMethod.GET, //
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public List<Survivor> getSurvivors() {
        List<Survivor> list = survivorDAO.getSurvivors();
        return list;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/survivors/{id}", //
            method = RequestMethod.GET, //
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })

    public Survivor getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return survivorDAO.getSurvivor(id);
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/survivors", //
            method = RequestMethod.POST, //
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })

    public Survivor addEmployee(Survivor s) {
        return survivorDAO.addSurvivor(s);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/survivors/{id}/{latitude}/{longitude}", //
            method = RequestMethod.PUT, //
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public Survivor updateLocation(@PathVariable("id") long id, @PathVariable("latitude")double latitude, @PathVariable("longitude")double longitude) {
                survivorDAO.updateLocation(id, latitude, longitude);
        return survivorDAO.getSurvivor(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "survivor/reportcontamination/{id}", //
            method = RequestMethod.PUT, //
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public void reportContamination(@PathVariable("id")long id){
            survivorDAO.reportContamination(id);
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{empNo}", //
            method = RequestMethod.DELETE, //
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        survivorDAO.deleteSurvivor(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `/ZombieNetwork` the context of your webapp? If not you should annotate your controller with `@RequestMapping("/ZombieNetwork")`

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19100239/1201725

Comment: Maybe this helps if you are using Eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522054/changing-tomcat-context-path-of-web-project-in-eclipse

Comment: As Riverside sugested, if you want to have yourSite.com/ZombieNetwork/survivors you should add the annotation to your controller. For your current configuration you can use yourSite.com/survivors

Comment: I added the annotation in my controller, but still getting the same error

Comment: Maybe you could post the exact request you're sending and provide the context the webapp is deployed at