# Find which url was used to access the controller when multiple url mapping to the same controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I see [Spring MVC multiple url mapping to the same controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078582/spring-mvc-multiple-url-mapping-to-the-same-controller-method)

So now I have a method defined as

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/aaa", "/bbb", "/ccc/xxx"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String foo() {
    // was it called from /aaa or /bbb
}
```

At run time, I want to know if the controller was called from `/aaa` or `/bbb`

Comment: You could use HttpServletRequest::getRequestURL then strip it and parse the uri.

Comment: Instead of passing HttpServletRequest object as argument for each controller method you can use [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). Take a look at this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()) which:

> Returns the part of this request's URL that calls the servlet. This
>   path starts with a "/" character and includes either the servlet name
>   or a path to the servlet, but does not include any extra path
>   information or a query string.

As follow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/aaa", "/bbb", "/ccc/xxx"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String foo(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String path = request.getServletPath(); // -> gives "/aaa", "/bbb" or "/ccc/xxx"
}
```